# My book doesn't have the answer again. Can anyone help me with volumes of solids by slicing?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I find the volume in the first octant bounded by the surfaces $y^2=z^2−x$ and $z=1$ Using the slice in the figure to compute the volume?

I have no clue on how to do this, I want a solution where I can explain it to someone else who does not know how to do this as well

[image: the figure]

Comment: Why not take some time to study the answers given to your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237253/my-book-doesnt-have-the-answer-can-anyone-help-me-with-volumes-of-solids-by-sl)?  Maybe similar techniques apply here.

Comment: cause I am studying for an exam later today. and I clearly dont know how am I going to solve this

Comment: There is no maybe. Techniques from the previous answer apply here. Try turning your head to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define a slice $$D_z = \{ x,\ y\geq 0,\ y^2+x\leq z^2 \},\
0<z<1$$

Then

\begin{align*}{\rm area}\ D_z &=
\int_0^z\int_0^{z^2-y^2} \ dxdy  \\&= \int_0^z (z^2-y^2)\ dy \\&=
\frac{2}{3}z^3 \\
{\rm Volume}&=\int_0^1 \ {\rm area}\ D_z\ dz\\
&= 1/6 \end{align*}